# Angular 4 + SASS path mapping

Tags: angular, sass

I was wondering if there is anyway to add path mapping for SASS files in Angular 4?
What I mean is, lets say I have global scss files stored in src/assets/styles and I would like to access these files in my component scss files which are stored in src/app/component/{component-name}/{component-name}.component.scss.
Currently I have to do:

```
@import "../../../assets/styles/{file-needed}.scss";
```

When I would like to be able to do something like:

```
@import "~assets/styles/{file-needed}.scss";
```

I know the ~ will go to the node_modules dir, that's just an example.
Is there anyway to create a shortcut for these kind of things?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.
You can add "stylePreprocessorOptions" to the angular-cli.json app object to include any path in your scss compilation.
Source is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles).

Answer (score 1):

**update 2019**

In **Angular 6** and newer, in `angular.json`

```
"projects": {
    "projectName": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules",
                "src/app/styles",
                "some/other/path/to/scss"
              ]
            },
            ...
```